# Grails slf4j NoSuchMethodError

Tags: grails, slf4j

Trying to compile a grails 1.3.7 app and getting the following dependency error. Any help?

```
> Error executing script RunApp:
> org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>   at
> org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.CorePluginFinder.loadCorePluginsFromResources(CorePluginFinder.java:93)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.CorePluginFinder.getPluginClasses(CorePluginFinder.java:54)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:363)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:326)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:282)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManager$loadPlugins.call(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
```

UPDATE: Currently I can grails clean and manually delete plugins; the first build works and all builds after that fail with the error above.

The plugins causing problems are quartz-1.0-RC1 and neo4j-1.0.0.M2.  A previous developer added this to the depedencies.groovy for those plugins

### Neo4j - added excludes below

```
 runtime("org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:$datastoreVersion","org.grails:grails-         datastore-core:$datastoreVersion") {
    excludes "jcl-over-slf4j", "slf4j-api"
 }
```

### Quartz - added slf4j-api

```
 excludes 'ehcache', 'xml-apis', 'commons-logging', 'slf4j-api'
```

### BuildConfig.Groovy

I tried adding this to my BuildConfig.groovy but it didn't work:

plugins {

```
    compile(":lesscss:1.0.0"){
           excludes "jcl-over-slf4j", "slf4j-api"
    }
    compile(":neo4j:1.0.0.M2"){
           excludes 'ehcache', 'xml-apis', 'commons-logging', 'slf4j-api'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread may be related to your problem: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/LocationAwareLogger-log-No-such-method-error-td3254387.html

I had the same issue and I ended up removing the wrong transitive dependency as suggested in the link above. I also had to forcefully remove a slf4j jar file that leaked somehow in the resulting war that leaded to the same error in deploying phase.